# AngularJS and non-javascript website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

I bought a book on AngularJS (no much time to read though right now :( ), and still not sure whether it's worth investing time in it.

The main presumes for the web app I'm developing are:

1. Main logic on server-side language (I'm using Symfony2 framework for this purpose)
2. Support for non-JS users
3. JS is mainly for visual effects and updated lists (like current logged in users), so probably (?) no data-binding feature is quite really needed, as I can achieve the same thing easily with refreshing a DIV with a list.

So, are there any cons for using AngularJS in such a web portal anyway?

And, especially, I'm interested in the 2nd point: what if a user has disabled JS - does AngularJS makes it more difficult to provide them a useful webpage than it normally is when using JavaScript for some (not crucial) purposes?

Thanks.

**Update:** I already wrote an extra more precise question in the comment: how do you think AngularJS is helpful when creating admin-like pages for e.g. data grids or tables - with view / sort / order / paging features (i.e. without edit)?

Comment: I think in the modern web development you cannot bypass Javascript.

Comment: If you disable JS and load an Angular App, it won't work properly at all. There is too much reliance on JavaScript. You'll see all your template code and no actual values, etc. If you just want to use JS for 'visual effects' then you don't want to use Angular.

Comment: @Simon Well, it's still possible :) I already implemented a number of features like rating, adding content etc. which use only HTML + PHP. You can use e.g. auto redirects for this purpose, which with a good framework are very easily achieved.

Comment: The vast majority of users do not disable Javascript. You should not design websites with them in mind. Facebook, Google, Ebay, and Amazon certainly don't.

Comment: As Brad Green famously pointed out, we live in 2015 - javascript is enabled everywhere

But if you insist on building websites for people who turn off javascript then AngularJS is probably not your choice.  You're better off with something isomorphic like ReactJS where the page can be rendered on the server.

Comment: @mGuv Thanks for your advice! I just see many devs using and praising AngularJS and looking for any opportunity to use it these days... So, let's say I'm considering using it only for the admin pages, like interactive data grids, tables, charts (but without need to edit values, just to view, sort etc.) - is AngularJS useful / helpful for this purpose?

Comment: @JamesG. such large corps like the ones you mentioned, sink within all this marketing stuff, and want obviously to make any possible way they can track our moves. I would not look at them in any non-crucial aspect when wanting to "build something else", than just copying :)